# Does this roof vent flashing need replacement?

Tags: roof, vent, shingles

We had a water heater and vent put in 15 years ago. It looked odd from the start with some sort of metal mesh and sealer, which I assume is a patch job. Is that the normal way to do patch? We had them come back months later because it was leaking (during rain), and they resealed.

I think it’s been good all these years, maybe it’s had a slow leak. But now it’s definitely leaking. Is this even a proper installation? Should the whole thing be redone?

[image: vent]

Comment: The problem is, that isn't flashing. It's  "I don't have flashing with me and by the time anyone notices I did it wrong I'll be long gone."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yea, it's a mess. If you interrupt the line of the shingles you need some flashing to divert the water, and that should run under the flight of shingles above, and bridge the gap to the shingles below...Which don't exist in this case.

They've just tarred the crap out of it and hoped for the best (which is a valid strategy if you use enough tar, and you reapply often).

I'd say it depends on the overall status of your roof, and how visible this thing is to the world. There are a dozen ways to waterproof this that aren't as good as actually getting some guys to *fix* it, but which will hold you for a few more years, if you're going to need a new roof in a few more years anyway.

On the other hand, if this is easily visible, it's a bit of an eyesore, and you might want to pay for the patch.

Comment: Yeah, looks like they just tarred the shirt out of it and the tar has deteriorated over the years under the hot sun.

Answer (score 11):

That mesh is not meant to be used on the roof as it has no function there. One would need large amount of roof sealnt to close all the holes.

It needs to be replaced with non porous sheet metal.